# How can I change this format to be datetime format? (python)

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset which contains some columns with datetime. My problem is, I found this type datetime format:

Apr'11
Apr-11
Apr 11

How can I automatically change this format to be datetime format?

Answer (score 2):

for you can use datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime
```

this is the link if you want any confusion

```
date_string = "Apr'11"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%b'%d")
```

%b = Locale’s abbreviated month name. (like Apr, Mar, Jan, etc)
%d = Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31]

```
date_string_2 = "Apr-11"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%b-%d")

date_string_3 = "Apr 11"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%b %d")
```

You should write this "%b %d" same as like date_string otherwise it will give you, even if you give an extra space.

go to this link to learn more about this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: that's mean I can do it one by one. My problem is I have some others like that, such as Jan-Des and from 11-15. How can I do change it automatically?

Comment: If you have 5 to 6 date formats, then you can use **for loop** `for date in dates` and in that for loop you can use **if-else condition**, it will automatically change if you have some

Comment: can you write down how is the code, please?